# Is it possible to serve my static blog with Angular?

Tags: angular, proxy, gatsby

We have to sites

- One for our static web pages (Angular)
- One for our blog (Gatsby)

Currently, we have a proxy pass at Apache level to redirect on respective sites. 
If URL consist /blog , apache should redirect to gatsby. Else it should redirected to Angular site.

It's working fine. But sometimes we are getting 404 pages.

Is it possible to serve my gatsby static blog folder through Angular directly? As we tried to copy our gatsby static files into dist folder of Angular but it's not working properly.

What is the better approach to handle such scenrios

Comment: When you mean sometimes we are getting 4040 pages you mean in specific URLs or in which scenarios?

Comment: the 404 issue is normally due to wrong config in angular

Comment: this may help you : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/